When I tried to count the string of translated language (tamil) in Python, it didn't give me the correct count why?
code
I tried to count the string for the name 'KUMAR' with length function, output came  5 it is correct.
But when I tried to count the same name in a different language(Tamil) the output I expected was 3 because
'குமார்' is a three letter word in Tamil but the output came 6.

Would you consider a ligated form like ஶ்ரீ one or two letters?

The len() function counts the Unicode code points (unique numbers that represent a character in the Unicode standard). My guess is that each character (grapheme) in Tamil consists of two Unicode code points and this is what len() counts.
You can use the regex (not re) module to get the correct count.
pip install regex
In this example:
import regex

def count_graphemes(text):
    return len(regex.findall(r'\X', text))


english_name = 'KUMAR'
tamil_name = 'குமார்'


print(f"Length of {english_name}: {count_graphemes(english_name)}")
print(f"Length of {tamil_name}: {count_graphemes(tamil_name)}")

the output is:
Length of KUMAR : 5
Length of குமார் : 3


Extended Grapheme Clusters should be sufficient for Tamil, so \X will do the job, but that isn't the case will all Indic scripts, where tailored grapheme clusters are required. The results given by regex can differ from those given by pyuegc or pyicu.
